# Notepad++ - Select whole line that contains a string with space

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to select whole line that contains the word `State Province`.

Fro the Search menu > Find, using `(.*State.*)` will select whole line that contains the word `State`. But using `(.*State\sProvince.*)` does not.

What's the correct regex command?

Comment: Some points: (1) it's generally better to ensure the whole line matches, regardless of any RE flavours or settings, by using `^` and `$` (inside or outside the brackets, though these seem unnecessary); (2) you can use a literal space instead of `\s`; (3) if you select `State Province` before `Find` then the string will appear as the default search string, to which you can add the pre- and post-ambles; now (4) you can replace the space with `\s` if you wish, and you may see other characters in the document string, including duplications, tabs or other space characters (eg non-breaking).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### What's the correct regex command?

`(.*State\sProvince.*)` works for me.

[image]

Please check the other settings in the "Find" dialog.

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: My mistake, I mistyped! Should've slept before doing more work last night. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That works just fine for me. You might have an extra space, so try adding an asterisk after the \s, so it reads `(.*State\s*Province.*)`